# text input component

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to ignore white space between characters inside a text input field
let's say  a user types in  "bri an"  instead of "brian.
Is there a way that white space is ignore and treated it as one word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many ways is to use the TextField.restrict property. Simply prevent spaces from being typed into your textfield in the first place by doing this:

```
myTextField.restrict = "^ ";
```

The ^ means to disallow the following characters (in this case we are disallowing a space).

I put an example on wonderfl http://wonderfl.net/c/teOC